# Validate <select> using jQuery Tools Validator plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html

Does anyone know how to validate select elements with it? I've added required="required" but no validation is done. I think it might be because there is always one option value available in a select. The docs say

> This attribute works also with checkbox and `<select>` fields

When talking about using the required attribute so I'm assuming it should work.

Any ideas? I'm using it successfully for a multi-page form with other field types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. sorted it.  I needed to add a 'pattern' attribute to the main 'select' tag the same way I was doing for normal 'input' tags.